# How do I allow the logger command to run using non superuser (sudo) privileges?

Tags: security, logs, sudo

I've been trying to run the logger command in terminal but it only works with sudo.

How do I allow it to work in terminal without the sudo command?  I'm trying to run the logger command from sleepwatcher (it doesn't seem to work in other apps like keyboard maestro).  I've tried to update the privileges of the system.log file to allow more permissions.

Perhaps it is a permissions problem because it runs in sudo mode and in terminal.

This doesn't log anything when run in terminal (or sleepwatcher or keyboard maestro or anywhere else)

```
logger -p info -t atreeon_test "hello"
```

This does log correctly when run in terminal

```
sudo logger -p info -t atreeon_test "hello";2
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what's going on. You are not the admin of this Mac? What do you mean "an app that has the admin user level"? (Normally, apps run as the user that launched them.) Does it have to be the system log, and not just some other text file? What OS version?

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy, I am the admin of the mac.  My user is admin level.  Sorry for any confusion.  The other app is just an app called sleepwatcher that runs whenever the mac goes into and out of sleep mode.  I'm on 14.2.1 (latest update).